# ActionMailer can't access helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, helper

I built an ActionMailer and it works well.

Now I am configuring a helper and trying to use in my `contact_mailer.html.erb`. 
It doesn't raise errors but the mail has not been sent.

In my `application_mailer.rb`

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application
  default from: 'Customer Service<service@example.com>'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

My `contact_mailer.rb`

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def order_notice(order)
    @order = order
    mail(to: @order.email, subject: 'Your order has been placed')
  end
end
```

My `application_helper.rb` like below:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def item_price_in_euro(price)
    @ratio_id = session[:ratio]
    @money_ratio = MoneyRatio.find(@ratio_id).ratio
    @eur_ratio = MoneyRatio.find(@ratio_id = 2).ratio

    ((price/@money_ratio)*@eur_ratio).to_i
  end

end
```

I tried the method, `item_price_in_euro(price)` in other regular view templates and it works. But when I use in the contact_mailer.html.erb, nothing happend. Here is my `contact_mailer.html.erb`

```
<% @order.product_items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item_price_in_euro(item.price) %> #<%= item.price %> works well.
<% end %>
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my codes?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your mailer file, it should help.

```
add_template_helper ApplicationHelper
```

Comment: I had tried the method that you provided and it didn't work for me. I think the problem may be my helper method and I'm trying to fix it.